# ASP.NET GridView_RowEditing get value of cell

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

This is pretty basic stuff, but I am unable to extract the text from a cell in my gridview.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rolle" SortExpression="role">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="roleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("role") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList style="width: 200px;" ID="roleDropdown" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDropDownlist" DataTextField="role" DataValueField="roleID"></asp:DropDownList>
     </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

```
Protected Sub GridView1_rowediting(sender As Object, e As GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowEditing

    Dim tb As Label
    tb = CType(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).FindControl("roleLabel"), Label)
    Dim userRoleString As String = tb.Text

End Sub
```

I received this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How do i extract the text from the cell in a GridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you need to find the control you want first then grab the text, something like this:

```
Dim tb as TextBox 
tb = CType(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).FindControl("ID_Of_Some_textbox"), TextBox)
Dim userRoleString As String = tb.Text
```

**EDIT: Added Sample code**

The basic Idea:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="user_id" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="user_name" SortExpression="user_name">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="user_name" 
                    DataValueField="user_name" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("user_name") %>' >
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("user_name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: The text is not in a textbox.

Comment: shouldn't matter - you have a control in the gridview that is holding data yes?

Comment: Yes <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="Brugernavn" SortExpression="username" /> but it cant have a id, i would like to get the text before the row goes into edit mode, because i substitute the text in the cell with a dropdownlist, and i want the dropdownlist to have the the same text selected as the text that was in the cell

Comment: that's a bit more complicated - but in a nutshell: edit your column list, highlight the username field, and convert it to a template field. then look at the markup.  you'll see the field expanded out into more manageable pieces.  replace the `<EditItemTemplate>` `TextBox` control with a `DropdownList` whose pre-selected value is the string you retrieve from the `Label` in the `<ItemTemplate>`

Comment: there is second level of complexity if you want that DropdownList associated with rows from a database **AND** that list of names is the same for all rows, just differing by the pre-selected name, then you can create one datasource outside the gridview and set it as the datasource for the dropdownlist that is inside the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in RowDataBound

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = 0;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow &&
    (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit)
        {
            // Here you will get the Control you need like:
            DropDownList dl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlDriverID1");
            foreach (ListItem li in dl.Items)
            {
                if (li.Text == ((System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Row.DataItem)).Row.ItemArray[19].ToString())
                {
                    dl.SelectedIndex = index;
                    break;
                }
                index += 1;
            }

        }
    }
```